# TAPS: Can't validate: "Required commands for metadata missing (\acmBooktitle ). title "

Tags: acm

Trying to submit a paper to ACM. Used the ACM template in Overleaf. When validating, I'm getting the following error.

"Required commands for metadata missing (\acmBooktitle ). We have identified that these mandatory commands are missing in your source file. Please update your source file to include \acmBooktitle"

I tried emailing TAPS support but no response. The link given in the validation error log doesn't work (404). First time using LATEX so I have no idea how to fix this. Help!?

Comment: well did you try to add a `\acmBooktitle {something}` to your tex file?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. I don't know where or how. I cannot find help on this issue. What does this error even mean? Where am I supposed to add this and why isn't it already in the template?

Comment: Look you wrote the paper and have the tex file, so you are much better placed than me to add something to it.

Comment: I don't even know what it's asking for. How is it not built into the ACM template? What is it asking for exactly?

Comment: The request is quite clear "Please update your source file to include \acmBooktitle". So you could look up in the documentation what the command does and which syntax it has. Or you could make an educated guess that it has one argument and add somewhere in the preamble `\acmBooktitle {something}` and look what happens.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me at all. Is it asking me to add a book title, or add something in the source to include a command for booktitles? I don't understand why that wouldn't be in teh ACM template already. What source file is it referring to? I've got like 15 source files in this template?!

Comment: the source file is the tex. And I don't know why the template doesn't contain the command (I even don't know which template you use), ask the author of the template.